# Do anybody know a vector program with custom compound lines?

Tags: software-recommendation

If somebody don't know what I mean by compound lines. Here is example of use:[image]

[image]

I know that it is possible in some Cad programs, but they don't provide much possibilities for art.

Comment: Possibly a custom brush pattern?

Comment: I looking for a vector graphic program, so I can change lines I already drawn.

Comment: Illustrator brushes... vector.... and patterned brushes.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to better explain what technique you want to use. Compound lines is a very broad term and there's multiple ways of achieving what you've shown in, say, *Illustrator*. If you want a pattern to follow a path you've drawn, this is very achievable in *Illustrator*. In fact, its tools for this are far more evolved than line styles in *AutoCAD*, which provides very limited support for this technique.

Comment: I just watch some videos and it looks that adobe illustrator is the answer. I used term compound lines, cause I know this term from both AutoCad and ArchiCad. Sims that in graphic design it have another name.

Comment: In general I'd recommend describing the technique rather tools or naming conventions if you're asking a question that traverses software packages or media. They all have their own naming conventions and you risk alienating someone who knows the answer. As @Scott mentioned, I think you'll find what you need with *Adobe Illustrators* pattern brush tool.

Comment: Adobe Illustrator pattern brushes can do this, as well as Inkscape's pattern along a path functionality. Inkscape is free.

Answer (score 1):

Ada,

I'm an ArchiCAD user like you, and so understand your usage of "compound lines".

AFAIK *any* decent vector design program in typical use supports this, whether Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer or InkScape.

They're most commonly called brushes, or pattern brushes or vector brushes, and you define the pattern by drawing it with the pen or bezier tool, and then having selected the elements you're applying, you define the brush pattern.

Each application will have its own specifics: most will respect line weights in your sample (unlike ArchiCAD); some may prefer you to expand or explode stroke into fills; others won't.

Should not be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Corel Draw has a tool called Artistic Medium that transforms a simple line (A) into a decoration (B)

[image]

You can invent your own patterns.